# Difference between first time paypal subscription and every month for monthly subscription using php?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I want to sent email to client using ipn, when automatically money deduct from subscriber account on every month. I have getting paypal variables from paypal. Can I check using this variables?

Answer (score 0):

If you have IPN set up, the client's email address will be one of the things sent to you in the IPN notice.

Check out the `payer_email` variable in the [IPN reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/).